# Connection reset by peer.socket write error in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to **JMeter** and I am getting an error in **Jmeter**

> Response code:Non HTTP response code:Java.net.SocketException Response
>   message: Non HTTP response message: Connection reset by peer.socket
>   write error.

Is this an easy fix?

Comment: Please describe your question more clearly.  Add some code will be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you totally sure that this is a problem on JMeter, not application under test side, you can try working it around as follows:

1. In *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
2. In *hc.parameters* file:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up.

References:

- [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks For your reply Dmitri. I did try this settings earlier. But keep getting  same error message. I am using JMeter3. Client and server both got java 1.7

Comment: I would suggest checking your application under test logs for any suspicious entries and also consider monitoring server-side health metrics with i.e. [PerfMon plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). It might be the case your server is overloaded hence it cannot process that much incoming requests. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for detailed PerfMon setup and usage instructions